# Invariance of Correlation length under Coarse graining

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory

I am following Mehran Kardar's lectures on Statistical Mechanics II. In this lecture note https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-334-statistical-mechanics-ii-statistical-physics-of-fields-spring-2014/85f01760f2ea1193c673baffce5c25e6_MIT8_334S14_Lec7.pdf, He states that the correlation length reduces by a factor of b **solely** because of the rescaling of the fields. But this would be true assuming that the correlation length is invariant after the coarse graining step. But since the coarse graining step involves summing over many possible configurations, why would the correlation length remain invariant since the same separation in magnetic moments/fields will now involve sums of multiple configurations that can potentially enhance or reduce the correlation strength? especially since the probabilities of field configurations will change after coarse graining